# nvidia driver parameters - missing some?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, xorg, nvidia, gpu

I apologize for the crosspost, but I [posted this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1302193/751380) and some related ones in askubuntu and they just aren't getting any
traction there, even after I took my meager rep there and applied a bounty.  Can someone here help?

---

I've been struggling with getting my nvidia GPU to work, as detailed in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300461/cant-set-resolution-higher-than-800x600-on-nvidia-card) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299607/2nd-monitor-detected-but-no-display) I posted recently.  Everything was working fine until a few weeks ago, when suddenly, with no obvious associated event, the nVidia card stopped producing output under linux (works fine in Windows).  Since then, I've done a lot of digging and found [this incredibly in depth answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/727897/751380) which listed all sorts of troubleshooting tools and tips.

One of the tips was to list the driver parameters using the following command:

`sudo sh -c "ls /sys/module/<driver-module-from-lshw>/parameters/ | xargs -L1 -i{} sh -c 'echo -n {} \" \" ; cat /sys/module/<driver-module-from-lshw>/parameters/{}'"`

I have two video cards - one is radeon, the other nvidia.  The output of the above command with the radeon driver generates many parameters.  The nvidia one gives a single parameter, which seems strange to me.

Shouldn't a working driver have more parameters?  I'm asking this to see if this is a clue for my larger problem.

At the very least, can someone post samples of their working nvidia driver parameters?

```
$ driver=nvidia
$ sudo sh -c "ls /sys/module/$driver/parameters/ | xargs -L1 -i{} sh -c 'echo -n {} \" \" ; cat /sys/module/$driver/parameters/{}'"
nv_cap_enable_devfs  1
--------------------------------------------
$ driver=radeon
$ sudo sh -c "ls /sys/module/$driver/parameters/ | xargs -L1 -i{} sh -c 'echo -n {} \" \" ; cat /sys/module/$driver/parameters/{}'"
agpmode  -1
aspm  -1
audio  -1
auxch  -1
backlight  -1
bapm  -1
benchmark  0
cik_support  1
connector_table  0
deep_color  0
disp_priority  0
dpm  -1
dynclks  -1
fastfb  0
gartsize  1024
hard_reset  0
hw_i2c  0
lockup_timeout  10000
modeset  1
msi  -1
mst  0
no_wb  0
pcie_gen2  -1
r4xx_atom  0
runpm  -1
si_support  1
test  0
tv  1
use_pflipirq  2
uvd  1
vce  1
vm_block_size  12
vm_size  8
vramlimit  0
```

System details:

- Ryzen 5, no integrated graphics
- B450 Tomahawk Max motherboard
- ADATA SX8100 512 GB SSD
- Nvidia GeForce 1660 main GPU
- Radeon HD 5450 secondary GPU
- Dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 and windows 10
- UEFI firmware
- No overclocking or other tweaks
- no xorg.conf, using auto-config

in case it's helpful, I'll post the output of various commands in the referenced post to give details of my system:

[sudo sh -c "lsb_release -sd; dmidecode -s system-product-name; echo ==; lshw -c display; echo ==; xrandr --verbose; echo ==; cat /etx/X11/xorg.conf"](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wjWB3ddVcn/)

[cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CqfdzhBXrt/)

[ls /sys/class/drm/*/edid | xargs -i{} sh -c "echo {}; parse-edid < {}"](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bhmSjn2RXq/)

[xtrace xrandr --output HDMI-1-0 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of HDMI-1](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/k7h373bYmD/)

[modinfo nvidia](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gmTtrwtvHb/)

```
cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version gives:

NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  455.38  Thu Oct 22 06:06:59 UTC 2020
GCC version:  gcc version 10.2.0 (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1)
```

Comment: Check with "lsmod | grep nvidia", you may be looking for another nvidia module.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille:  lsmod | grep nvidia lists these modules:  nvidia, nvidia_modeset, nvidia_drm, nvidia_uvm, i2c_nividia_gpu.  lspci -vnn shows that the kernel modules in use for my nvidia card is "nvidia".  listed kernel modules are "nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia".  I'm not sure which other module I should be looking for?

Comment: Where is nouveau "listed"? Run modinfo for the nvidia_drm and _modeset.  Why do you expect  more parameters? Never once did I set a kernel parameter for a proprietary nvidia driver before I got myself a laptop with hybrid amd/nvidia graphics. Even there it was no use, can't get the very expensive tu116m to work on linux.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille:  in the output of lspci -vnn, it lists "Kernel driver in use: nvidia" followed by "Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia" on the next line.  and I'm not trying to "set" a kernel parameter.  I'm trying to diagnose if there is something wrong with my driver, since my card isn't producing any output. It was working about a month ago, and works under windows.  See my linked questions in the OP.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille:  'modinfo nvidia_drm':  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tWtXFjJnrc/
'modinfo nvidia_modeset':  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rVG2GF2dNJ/

what am I looking for in the output of this command?

Comment: "when suddenly, with no obvious associated event, " your kernel dates from 9/12, two weeks ago?  Please add Xorg.0.log from immediately after reboot. "No xorg.conf", but you post one?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille:  This problem started before I updated my kernel as part of moving from 20.04 to 20.10, which I hoped would fix the problem.  I have no Xorg.conf - cat'ing it was just part of the command I took from post that helped me troubleshoot.  It returns "No such file or directory" to stderr, you can see it's not in the pastebin.  Here is my Xorg.0.log immediately after boot.  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TN8ksSptgd/

Comment: Two problems in there: last line "Failed to open authorization file "/var/run/sddm/..."  and earlier  nvidia setting mode "NULL".

Comment: @GerardH.Pille:  hunh.  that's a little bizzare.  That error is in my current Xorg.0.log, but the referenced file exists.   :~$ grep sddm  /var/log/Xorg.0.log   gives: 
[    23.422] (EE) Failed to open authorization file "/var/run/sddm/{d935926f-a2e6-4033-bb88-45a0e923d242}": No such file or directory   :~$ ls -l /var/run/sddm/ gives:
-rw------- 1 sddm sddm 52 Dec 24 13:25 {d935926f-a2e6-4033-bb88-45a0e923d242}

Comment: That file exists now. I've never heard of "sddm". Yet another "display manager"?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille:  sddm is the "simple desktop display manager". https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SDDM

Answer (score 1):

According to [a gentoo discussion forum](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1097502.html) this may be a fix:

```
option nvidia-drm modeset=1
```

put this in a /etc/modprobe.d/XXX.conf file.

Comment: I tried this, both in the modprobe file and by passing "nvidia-drm.modeset=1" directly in the kernel parameters.  It appeared to make no impact.